# how to send an alert message by telegram bot?

Tags: php, php-telegram-bot

i want to send timed message likes @alertbot, my code like this. but at 20.30 the bot doesnt send any message.

```
date_default_timezone_set("mytimezone");
$time = date(H:i);
$date = date(d/m/Y);

$pesan = “/alert 20:30 27/04/2017 some texts”;
$chatid = 13245;

$texts = explode(“ “,$pesan,4);
$message = $texts[0];

switch ($message) {
    case ‘/alert’:
      $times = $texts[1];
      $dates = $texts[2];
      $text  = $texts[3];

    while ($times == $time && $dates == $date) {
       sendMessage($chatid,$text);  
       break;
// the bot will stop after sendMessage to chatid
    }
}
```

what's wrong with my script?

Comment: date(H:i:s) will include seconds and will not match 20:30

Comment: oh thank you, but i've changed to date(H:i) the bot still doesnt send message at time.

Comment: I notice that your time is not a valid string. $times = "20:30"; should work better. Same goes for your date.

Comment: And without knowing what sendMessage actually does I don't really see the point in having a while loop which you break after the first execution anyways, why not use a simple if?

Comment: sorry miss on typing, actually date and time was from data array.

Comment: That was impossible to read, please edit your questions if you have updates to your code.

Comment: How is your code called? Only when someone sends a message or via cron? If you are only aswering to messages the bot won't send any message by itself. You would instead have to use cron to run your script and store the requested alarms either as direct cronjobs (which i don't recommend) or in a database using a timestamp.

Comment: yes, only when someone sends a message. oh thank you @TobiasF. i will try to use database using a timestamp,

Comment: cron is the solution for the timing, create e.g. a PHP-file which checks all of the entries with their timestamps and run it via cron in a regular interval.

Comment: @achmad311 did it worked?

Comment: @TobiasF. not yet, still trying. i'm new on this so may be it will take a more time. but i know what should i do,